# could not open .jade file using Terminal : "-bash:jade:command not found"

Tags: node.js, pug

pug or named jade was installed before the code running.
The error is 'jade:command not found'

Comment: have you installed it globally ? `npm install -g jade` ?

Comment: yes i did.  fixed now. due to I am using Mac . So I have to install like 'sudo npm install pug -g'. I forgot 'sudo'..... How stupid i am.  anyway thank you